# Questions about useCallback hook and anonymous function

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-hooks, anonymous-function, usecallback

When passing a callback function, especially when passing a **parameterized** function, I know that I should use the `useCallback` hook because the use of anonymous functions can adversely affect performance.

the example of anonymous function I said is like this.

```js
import React, { useState } from 'react';

const Component = () => {
  const [param, setParam] = useState('');
  ...

  return (
    ...
    <SomeComponent
      onClick={() => setParam('parameter')}
      {...others}
    />
  );
}
```

In the process of converting an anonymous function to use this hook, I encountered an error saying 'Too many renders' or it didn't work properly.
But I don't know exactly in what situation and in what situation.

and I used `useCallback` like below.

```js
import React, { useState, useCallback } from 'react';

const Component = () => {
  const [param, setParam] = useState('');

  const handleClick = useCallback((params) => {
    setParam(params);
  },[]);

  ...
  return (
    ...
    <SomeComponent
      onClick={handleClick('parameter')}
      {...others}
    />
  );
}
```

However, when using an anonymous function to return within `useCallback`, it also worked.

This means code like here. (Only the differences compared to the code above.)

```js
  const handleClick = useCallback((params) => {
    return () => setParam(params);
  },[]);
```

In this situation, I wonder if it's worse than just using an anonymous function inside the `useCallback` if I simply use an anonymous function instead of using this hook.

Comment: If your function is as small as that, I doubt you'll gain any performance by even using `useCallback`..  But you loose a lot of readability instead, when -> `onClick={(params) => setParam(params)}` would do the same.

Comment: @Keith thanks for the comment. But that code is just an example. Maybe it was an inappropriate example.
And the point of my question was, "Is the same performance penalty when returning anonymous functions within` useCallback` just using anonymous functions? "

In other words, people recommend using `useCallback` because anonymous functions have a negative impact on performance, and I wonder if I can use them if they work correctly when I return an anonymous function inside` useCallback`.

Comment: use `useCallback` when you need to optimize child re-renders by passing the same reference of the function and the child component is `PureComponent`/wrapped with `React.memo`, although it remembers the previous function reference a new function is getting created on every re-render but gets garbage collected.

Comment: Okay. Thanks for the comment. It helped a lot!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
  const handleClick = useCallback((params) => {
    setParam(params);
  },[]);

  ...
  return (
    ...
    <SomeComponent
      onClick={handleClick('parameter')}
      {...others}
    />
  );
```

in the above code during first render, at this statement `"onClick={handleClick('parameter')}"` handleClick function is called with a string named "parameter". since handleClick has setParam("parameter"), it will update state. updating state will cause re-render which will again come to same statement  `"onClick={handleClick('parameter')}"` causing infinte loop.

following code you added later works because you are not updating state, instead returning a function, which acts as onclick handler.

```
const handleClick = useCallback((params) => {
    return () => setParam(params);
  },[]);
```

better way of doing this shoud be as follwing,

```
import React, { useState, useCallback } from 'react';

const Component = () => {
  const [param, setParam] = useState('');

  const handleClick = useCallback((params) => {
    setParam(params);
  },[]);

  ...
  return (
    ...
    <SomeComponent
      onClick={handleClick}
      {...others}
    />
  );
}
```

coming back to your question , comparing performance depends on the other function definitions and **render times of child compoents** inside return function inside your Compoenent.
let's say you have another onclickHanldier named 'anotherHandleClick' inside your app.
then your component looks like this

```
const Component = () => {
  const [param, setParam] = useState('');
  const [anotherParam, setAnotherParam] = useState('');

  const handleClick = (params) => {
    setParam(params);
  };
const anotherHandleClick =(params) => {
    setAnotherParam(params);
  };
  ...
  return (
    ...
    <SomeComponent
      onClick={handleClick('parameter')}
      {...others}
    />
<SomeComponent
      onClick={antherHandleClick('parameter')}
      {...others}
    />
  );
}
```

in the above component when any one of "SomeCompoenent" clicked entiere "Component" re-renders, so the handler functions are newly defined.and when both 's does referential equality check on onclick handler functions, they believe it is new handler function which casues them to render both.
in that case it is better to use useCallBack hook as following,

```
const Component = () => {
  const [param, setParam] = useState('');
      const [anotherParam, setAnotherParam] = useState('');

  const handleClick = useCallback((params) => {
    setParam(params);
  },[]);
const anotherHandleClick = useCallback((params) => {
    setAnotherParam(params);
  },[]);
  ...
  return (
    ...
    <SomeComponent
      onClick={handleClick('parameter')}
      {...others}
    />
<SomeComponent
      onClick={antherHandleClick('parameter')}
      {...others}
    />
  );
}
```

in the above code when any one  is clicked , state changes. then when rendering, useCallback make sure that onclick handler refernces didn't change. so  having dependency of onclick handlers won't be rerendered.

so final thought is ***It's creating a function on each render in both cases. the second (because it'e wrapped in a useCallback) will return the memoized function created on the initial render***

when to use useMemo or useCallback [refer this](https://kentcdodds.com/blog/usememo-and-usecallback)

Comment: Thank you for your answer.
But as you said in the third block of code, I wrote it before I asked this question, but in this case, it didn't work because no parameters were passed.
Maybe because I wrote the example so much simpler than the situation I was having trouble with.
So your point is that if I write like the last code I wrote in the question, it's not good for performance?

Comment: when only one function definition is there, using useCallBack is over head as it does one extra step than inline handlers. usually react render is very fast.
but when your component has multiple function definitoins and dependent child components whose render time is very hight,better use useCallBack.
please read this: https://kentcdodds.com/blog/usememo-and-usecallback for better understanding.
and let me know if you get better perspective that i can also learn.

Comment: Oh, I understood what you mean. thanks for your kindful comment!

Comment: hope you learned something. i edited answer and added bolded description which explains the difference basically. 
you are welcome:)

Answer (score 0):

In your code:

```js
const handleClick = useCallback((params) => {
    setParam(params);
  },[]);
```

You should pass the parameters into the second argment of `useCallback` like so:

```js
const handleClick = useCallback((params) => {
    setParam(params);
  },[setParam,param, SETPARAMACTUALVALUE]); 
// Change SETPARAMACTUALVALUE to whatever the variable name is for the `setParam` hook
```

Comment: Oh, I hurried and made a mistake in the code I wrote as an example. Sorry.
But the point of my question was, "Does returning anonymous functions inside` useCallback` degrade performance just like using anonymous functions only? "

Answer (score 0):

useCallback hook usage will be better if you want to save the function until hook's dependency changed. It gives you better performance because the hook remember internal function.